# I want to stop CLLocationManager when I touch the home button--iphone

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie of iphone developerment world.
I want to stop `CLLocationManager` when I touch the home button.
Can anyone tell me how should i do that?

Comment: can you add a little bit of code to your question to show how you are invoking (creating and starting) your CLLocationManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's docs:

> When the user presses the Home button or the system launches another
>   app, the foreground app transitions to the inactive state and then to
>   the background state. These transitions result in calls to the app
>   delegate’s `applicationWillResignActive:` and
>   `applicationDidEnterBackground:` methods
>
> applicationDidEnterBackground: Tells the delegate that the application
>   is now in the background.
>
> `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> application: The singleton application instance.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> In iOS 4.0 and later, this method is called instead of the
>   applicationWillTerminate: method when the user quits an application
>   that supports background execution. You should use this method to
>   release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store
>   enough application state information to restore your application to
>   its current state in case it is terminated later. You should also
>   disable updates to your application’s user interface and avoid using
>   some types of shared system resources (such as the user’s contacts
>   database). It is also imperative that you avoid using OpenGL ES in the
>   background.
>
> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to
>   perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform
>   any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the
>   system by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. In
>   practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as
>   quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs
>   out your application is terminated and purged from memory.
>
> You should perform any tasks relating to adjusting your user interface
>   before this method exits but other tasks (such as saving state) should
>   be moved to a concurrent dispatch queue or secondary thread as needed.
>   Because it's likely any background tasks you start in
>   applicationDidEnterBackground: will not run until after that method
>   exits, you should request additional background execution time before
>   starting those tasks. In other words, first call
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and then run the task on a
>   dispatch queue or secondary thread.
>
> The application also posts a
>   UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notification around the
>   same time it calls this method to give interested objects a chance to
>   respond to the transition.
>
> For more information about how to transition gracefully to the
>   background, and for information about how to start background tasks at
>   quit time, see [iOS Application Programming
>   Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html).